# JSP Form and Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a form in a JSP page, which show a confirm window in javascript before submitting the form. I want to do that when the user clicks ok, the servlet handle that "event" and make an action, but only if the user click ok. I have some idea, but i don't know how can i complete it

My Form.jsp

```
var conf=confirm("¿Está seguro que desea enviar la información ?);
if(conf==true){
                document.getElementById("EIBSBTN").style.visibility='hidden';
                //some field or variable that serves like a flag
                return true;
            }else{
                alert("Ha cancelado en envio de la información !!");
                //some field or variable that serves like a flag
                document.getElementById("EIBSBTN");
                return false;
```

My servlet.java

```
If (field or variable == true)
{
make something;
else
make something else;
}
```

Thanks in advance

P.D. Sorry for my bad english, but i'm struggling :D

Comment: well, i am making the procedure in that way, because in the servlet i will delete some data from the databases. I am using the onsubmit function to call to another function that has the confirm window. I don't know if i clarify what i am trying to do it... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could call the javascript function in the obSubmit handler for your [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement). If you click okay the form will submit, if you don't (because you return false) it won't. The servlet will not be called if the form isn't submitted.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="yourservlet" onsubimt="return confirm()">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script>
  var conf=confirm("¿Está seguro que desea enviar la información ?);
  if(conf==true){
       document.getElementById("EIBSBTN").style.visibility='hidden';
            //some field or variable that serves like a flag
            return true;
    }else{
       alert("Ha cancelado en envio de la información !!");
      //some field or variable that serves like a flag
       document.getElementById("EIBSBTN");
        return false;
   }
```

This way the request will only be sent to the servlet if the user click the ok button. Otherwise, your form will not be submitted to the servlet.